Number of dots in a dotted line
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\begin{center}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.59,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=0.1pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm
       }
     ] 



          
           \node (a0) at (0,0)[acteur,label=]{}; 

           \node (a1) at (1.5,0) [acteur,label=]{};
           \node (a2) at (3,1.5) [acteur,label=]{}; 

    \node (a3) at (3,3) [acteur,label=]{}; 
    \node (a4) at (3,4.5) [acteur,label=]{};
    \node (a5) at (1.5,6) [acteur,label=]{};
   \node (a6) at (0,6) [acteur,label=]{};
   \node (a7) at (-1.5,4.5) [acteur,label=]{};
 \node (a8) at (-1.5,3) [acteur,label=]{};
 \node (a9) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur,label=]{};
\node (a10) at (3,7.5) [acteur,label=]{};
\node (a11) at (3,9) [acteur,label=]{};
\node (a12) at (3,10.5) [acteur,label=]{};
\node (a13) at (1.5,12) [acteur,label=]{};
\node (a14) at (0,12) [acteur,label=]{};
\node (a15) at (-1.5,10.5) [acteur,label=]{};
\node (a16) at (-1.5,9) [acteur,label=]{};
\node (a17) at (-1.5,7.5) [acteur,label=]{};


\draw[dashed] (a0) -- (a1);
\draw[dashed] (a1) -- (a2); 
\draw [black](a2) -- (a3);
\draw[dotted](a3) -- (a4);

\draw[black](a4) -- (a5);
\draw [dashed](a5) -- (a6);
\draw[black](a6) -- (a7);
\draw[dotted](a7) -- (a8);
\draw[black](a8) -- (a9);
\draw[dashed](a9) -- (a0);
\draw[dashed](a10) -- (a5);
\draw[](a10) -- (a11);
\draw[dotted](a12) -- (a11);
\draw[](a12) -- (a13);
\draw[dashed](a13) -- (a14);

\draw[](a14) -- (a15);
\draw[dotted](a15) -- (a16);
\draw[](a16) -- (a17);
\draw[dashed](a17) -- (a6);
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}   
 \end{figure}

In the dotted line of the graph, I just need only three dots. How one can get that.

Unrelated: You should note use the center env to center inside a float like figure. Both center and figure adds vertical spacing. Replace \begin{center} by \centering and delete \end{center}

Please extend your example to a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to help.

I tried, but could not make the figure

Instead of using \draw[dotted], use \path (which will not draw anything) and add node[sloped]{$\dots$} in the middle.
Note: You may want to add draw as an option to your acteur style to prevent the small space between the nodes and the edges. But maybe that's intentional.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.59, thick,
    acteur/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0.1pt, minimum size=0.2cm}] 

\node (a0) at (0,0)[acteur]{}; 
\node (a1) at (1.5,0) [acteur]{};
\node (a2) at (3,1.5) [acteur]{}; 
\node (a3) at (3,3) [acteur]{}; 
\node (a4) at (3,4.5) [acteur]{};
\node (a5) at (1.5,6) [acteur]{};
\node (a6) at (0,6) [acteur]{};
\node (a7) at (-1.5,4.5) [acteur]{};
\node (a8) at (-1.5,3) [acteur]{};
\node (a9) at (-1.5,1.5) [acteur]{};
\node (a10) at (3,7.5) [acteur]{};
\node (a11) at (3,9) [acteur]{};
\node (a12) at (3,10.5) [acteur]{};
\node (a13) at (1.5,12) [acteur]{};
\node (a14) at (0,12) [acteur]{};
\node (a15) at (-1.5,10.5) [acteur]{};
\node (a16) at (-1.5,9) [acteur]{};
\node (a17) at (-1.5,7.5) [acteur]{};

\draw[dashed] (a0) -- (a1);
\draw[dashed] (a1) -- (a2); 
\draw (a2) -- (a3);
\path (a3) --node[sloped]{$\dots$} (a4);
\draw (a4) -- (a5);
\draw [dashed](a5) -- (a6);
\draw (a6) -- (a7);
\path (a7) --node[sloped]{$\dots$} (a8);
\draw (a8) -- (a9);
\draw [dashed](a9) -- (a0);
\draw [dashed](a10) -- (a5);
\draw (a10) -- (a11);
\path (a12) --node[sloped]{$\dots$} (a11);
\draw (a12) -- (a13);
\draw[dashed] (a13) -- (a14);
\draw (a14) -- (a15);
\path (a15) --node[sloped]{$\dots$} (a16);
\draw (a16) -- (a17);
\draw[dashed] (a17) -- (a6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

